# How do I divide accross all columns in a pandas DF

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large data set with over 25 columns in a pandas df and I would like to calculate the growth rate from one month to the other.

How do I get from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

without having to repeat the formular 3 times like this;

```
growth_rate1 = (df['august'] / df['july'] - 1)
growth_rate2 = (df['september'] / df['august'] - 1)
growth_rate3 = (df['october'] / df['september'] - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html):

```
out = df.pct_change(axis=1).iloc[:,1:]
```